# Kubernetes DNS queries timeout

Tags: kubernetes, dns, coredns

We have a kubernetes cluster deployed on AWS EKS, and are experiencing intermittent timeouts on CoreDNS pods, usually clustered in groups of 5-15 failed queries in span of around 5 minutes. In a cluster, all queries regard the same hostname.

CoreDNS spits such logs:

```
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 example.com. A: read udp [coreDNSpodIP]:39068->172.16.0.2:53: i/o timeout
```

The cluster is deployed in a VPC with CIDR of `172.16.0.0/16`, tho I cant determine what's under `172.15.0.2`

They appear from time to time, we cannot reproduce the event that triggers them, nor correlate to any event on cluster. The coreDNS pods are working normally and at the same time are serving other queries well. What may be the cause and solution to fix the behavior?

Answer (score 2):

You may be hitting a limit after which all requests are throttled.

There are 2 things that come to mind

- [Enable DNS caching on CoreDNS](https://coredns.io/plugins/cache/)
- [Check for EC2 throttling issues](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dns-resolution-failures-ec2-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

For CoreDNS, there is one hard limit of **1024** packets per second (PPS) set at the ENI level.

> Let’s now assume that there is a sudden influx of DNS queries being made and the PPS is approaching the hard limit of 1024. At this point, we will start seeing DNS throttling and we will have no clue on the root cause of the problem as the natural troubleshooting intuition is to focus on CoreDNS pod and not on the ENI metrics. This ENI level hard limit can impact all of the microservices running on that specific worker node and it is important to constantly monitor this metric to avoid outages.

Related issue:

- May encounter occasional **UnknownHostException** errors
- `i/o timeout` log in CoreDNS

---

Solutions:

- Try increasing the number of CoreDNS replicas
- Implement [NodeLocal DNSCache](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/nodelocaldns/)

---

Monitoring:

- We could troubleshoot DNS throttling using the `linklocal_allowance_exceeded` metric with `ethtool`, for more details, please refer to the [Monitoring CoreDNS for DNS throttling issues using AWS Open source monitoring services](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/mt/monitoring-coredns-for-dns-throttling-issues-using-aws-open-source-monitoring-services/)

---

Source:

- [Monitoring CoreDNS for DNS throttling issues using AWS Open source monitoring services](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/blogs/mt/monitoring-coredns-for-dns-throttling-issues-using-aws-open-source-monitoring-services/)
- [Monitoring CoreDNS traffic for DNS throttling issues](https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/networking/CoreDNS/)